# Azure Application Gateway: Why when i hit its Public IP, i redirect to "<app_service_url>:80"?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice

I have an app service which runs web app.

I created application gateway on the front of wab app.

But when i hit Application Gatway's Public IP, i get redirected to `https://somename.azurewebsites.net:80/`

My Questions

1. Why it does not goes to go `<ApplicationGatwayPublicIP>` directly instead of `https://somename.azurewebsites.net:80/`
2. Let's assume that i accepte to `https://somename.azurewebsites.net:80/`. Why it adds 80 at the end (which i have to delete manually in oreder to work)?

Thank you in advance for your help!

PS: I will make some screenshot which can be helpul:

1. Backend Pool (app service):
   [image]
2. Backend Settings (for app service):

[image]

If you need more informations, please make me a comment

Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you need configure your backend pool with use of custom domain as below:

[image]

Make sure to ***add authentication/trusted root [certificates](https://youtu.be/i13At7cA9i4) of back-end servers*** and upload a certificate as below:

[image]

And configure a request to routing rule in setting under rules in backend targets try to add the ***Backend Pool which App Service*** has been configured and HTTP setting add which app ***gateway to connect app service*** and save

[image]

Once a backend pool is healthy stage now you can able to use public IP addresses that can be accessed directly. Now you can try to restrict access. check this similar [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/639587/azure-application-gateway-with-web-app-gateway-ip.html) answer by jeremy

***The main cause of issue you need to add custom domain Configure App Service with Application Gateway along with certificate.***

[image]

***Reference:***
[Manage traffic to App Service - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=customdomain%2Cazure-portal#edit-http-settings-for-app-service)